# open xsd file in web-inf/xsd

Tags: java, portlet, websphere-portal

I want to open the xsd file in the `web-inf/xsd/output.xsd`
This is what I am trying to do

`URL url = portletContext.getResource("WEB-INF/xsd/output.xsd");`

getResource returns URL but in my case I am getting `NullPointerException` and I need to supply this to the newFile to open the file.

`File newFile = new File("");`

I am confused how to get this working.

**UPDATE**

Please bear with my english. I got this working. I have a question, I have another file `*.xsl` file which would be used to generate the PDF. I cannot delete this file after opening, what would be the effect on the JVM if a file is left open I mean >100 users trying to create the PDF i.e., `*.xsl` file will be opened 100 times, in future application is used heavily by the users, does the GC automatically clear all the file descriptors opened?

Comment: It looks like you have already accepted an answer but I'm concerned why you would want to manually open a file in a portlet. That's generally bad sign for performance.

Comment: @NickRoth I want to generate a pdf file for the object. I have created an xsd and xslt file which would marshall the object and render a pdf output. Is this a wrong approach? Please let me know the best way

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you would be dynamically generating the same file over and over? Why not pre-generate that file and serve that? In general though, opening files while handling requests is not a good practice for performance. If you're opening a file during init() then it should be ok. I don't know all the requirements you need to fulfill so I can't really suggest a better option at the moment but just be mindful of the performance overhead that file IO can have on your application.

Comment: @NickRoth What happens if the file is left open, will there be a memory leak in future when the application is used heavily by the users ?

Comment: I don't know if your JVM will close the file once the File object has been garbage collected but thats not something you should hope for or depend on. If you want to open a file here be very sure to close it. Otherwise it could be as you mentioned and be essentially a memory leak. At some point either you run out of memory or you hit the max number of file handlers that can be open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the API doc of [javax.portlet.PortletContext](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/PortletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) it describes that:

... The path must begin with a slash (/) and is interpreted as relative to the current context root (which usually is the WebContent or web directory of your web application) 
This method allows the portlet container to make a resource available to portlets from any source. Resources can be located on a local or remote file system, in a database, or in a .war file.